# Xcode 15 #Preview macro breaks framework .swiftinterface

Tags: swiftui, xcode15

I have a simple view in my framework:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SimpleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello!")
    }
}

#Preview {
    SimpleView()
}
```

Notice how the `#Preview` macro is generated by `Xcode 15.0`. Now  when I build my framework (I create `xcframework`) and try to integrate it into an app, I can see this generated into `.swiftinterface` file:

```
public protocol SecretProtocol : MyFramework.SecretProtocolBase {
  func func1(_ foo: String, bar: String)
}
#Preview() <------------------------------- Error: Expressions are not allowed at the top level
public protocol ExtremelySecretProtocol {
  var var1: String? { get }
  var var2: String? { get }
}
```

And then it fails to build the application with:
[image]

Clearly the macro was not expanded and instead found it's way to the `.swiftinterface` file somehow. Is there a build setting or something similar that fixes this?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue? I'm having the same issue right now and I'm unsure what caused it?

Comment: Hi. No, I removed the macro for now and just used the old previews. I will give it a shot when the new Xcode is released and I have more time, maybe then it's gonna be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution for my case and it was, sadly, removal of the #Preview macro altogether.

This looks like a bug, but maybe I'm missing something and it's actually an expected behaviour.